# Whenever a SQL Die statement is invoked in php, i would like to have log to file or database

Tags: php

i need to store the following information:

1. DateTime of Die Statement
2. URL of the page that called the die Statement SQL Error Message SQL Query.

whenever i wrote PHP code like mysql_connect(...) or die(...) and mysql_connect,return false or didn't connect so error message in die,store in log file or database

Comment: what is an "SQL Die command" ??

Comment: Never heard of a DIE command in SQL, but if it did exist you would assume it would either terminate the current connection or shut the server down.  How are you meant to record that to the database if the database has been told to either disconnect you or shut down?

Comment: whenever i wrote PHP code like mysql_connect(...) or die(...) and  mysql_connect,return false or didn't connect so error message in die,store in log file or database.

Comment: So who told you to use `die()` in those cases? What prevents you to use `file_put_contents('file.txt', 'error message')` before your `die()` statement, or `mail`? On top of everything, you still use `mysql_*` functions which are completely obsolete by now..

Comment: Alright, calm down @N.B. - beginners have to start somewhere. Let the OP get it working before they get it perfect ;-)

Answer (score 1):

There is no die command in SQL. If you mean PHP code like `mysql_connect(...) or die(...)`, then no, you can't catch the die exactly, but you can alter the code to call your logging function instead:

```
mysql_connect(...) or log_connection_failure_then_exit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay let me say I am not a php developer. I may be wrong somewhere.

Instead of using die() method to handle error you can use try - catch this way:

```
try {
    $coonection = mysql_connect();
} catch($exception) {
    writeToFile($exception->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Only PDO throws a proper exception on connection failure. The PHP C-style database connection functions, like mysql_connect, return false and raise a warning on failure, which won't be caught by that. (Although OP has neglected to say what he's using.) Also, that would be `catch (Exception $exception)`. It's a parse error without the exception class name.